# Check if a $n$-dimensional hypercuboid fits through $n-1$ dimensional hypersphere

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Starting with 3 dimensions, let's say I have a cuboid with the edge lengths represented as $[a,b,c]$. I want to check if this cuboid can fit through a 2D circle with the diameter of $d$, based on the three primary projections (top, side, front). I can do it by finding all (in this case three) unique pairs of edges from $[a,b,c]$ that represent unique faces of the cuboid and compare the diagonal of each face with the diameter of the circle.

Can I apply the same reasoning when scaling both the cuboid and the "hole" to higher dimensions (while the number of dimensions of the cuboid is $N$ and the number of dimensions of the "hole" is $N-1$, always smaller by 1 as my professor suggested)?

Can I represent the edges of the hypercuboid as $[a,b,c,...]$ for $N$ dimensions, find the unique $N-1$-dimensional projections using the combinations of the edges and compare the diagonals of these projections with the diameter of a $N-1$-dimensional hypersphere?

Comment: In the hope of nudging you to answer your own question: All that matters is the length of the diagonal of a projection compared to the diameter of the (hyper-)spherical hole, because (i) any two orthogonal cross sections of a cuboid perpendicular to a particular axis are congruent, (ii) both the cross section section and the hole are convex. (You haven't said if the cuboid has to fit through a hole in _some_ axis orientation or _every_ axis orientation, which affects the answer.)

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. The cuboid has to fit through a hole in any axis orientation, sorry for not clarifying in the question. The diagonal of the projections can be calculated with $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ...}$ for higher dimensions as well, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that formula amounts to the Pythagorean theorem, and holds in arbitrary dimension. Given the clarification, you only need to find the "longest diagonal," which results from discarding the shortest side.

Comment: Thank you. I also wanted to ask whether my reasoning regarding the unique projections for higher dimensions is correct. While the number of of $m$-dimensional faces of a $n$-dimensional hypercube is $2^{n-m} {{n}\choose{m}}$ according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube#Faces), is the number of unique faces (i.e. faces with a unique diagonal that should be compared to the diameter) equal to just ${m}\choose{n}$?

Comment: If the goal is to slide a cuboid _parallel to one of its axes_ through a "spherical hole," the number of diagonals that need to be checked is just $n$; better, discard the length of a shortest side and use the remaining $(n-1)$ side lengths to calculate the diagonal. The "$n$ things" it suffices to check, in other words, are _side lengths_, not the complementary diagonals, which are harder to compute.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I fully understand the last part about the side lengths and complementary diagonals. Let's just say I have a $4$-dimensional cuboid and a $3$-dimensional "hole", does that mean I just need to check the diagonals of the $n=4$ $3$-faces/cells? That's without considering your suggestion of discarding the shortest side for now, as I feel it lets me grasp the problem a little better.

Comment: In a word, "yes." :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be more of a too-long-for-a-comment than a complete answer; still hoping to leave you some fun in working out details to your satisfaction.

To fix notation and terminology, let's say we have $n > 1$ positive real numbers $a_{k}$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$. Let's call the *cuboid* the $n$-fold Cartesian product
$$
C = \prod_{k=1}^{n} [0, a_{k}] = [0, a_{1}] \times [0, a_{2}] \times \cdots \times [0, a_{n}].
$$

Let $m$ be an integer with $1 \leq m < n$. (In the comments I was assuming $m = n - 1$.) Let's define an $m$-dimensional *slice* of $C$ to be the $m$-dimensional cuboid we obtain by selecting one of $\binom{n}{m}$ sets of $m$ coordinates and replacing the *other* $n - m$ factors in the product by the singleton set $\{0\}$.

If the lengths of the sides are denoted $b_{1}$, $b_{2}$, \dots, $b_{m}$, the *diameter* of the slice is
$$
\sqrt{b_{1}^{2} + b_{2}^{2} + \cdots + b_{m}^{2}} = \biggl(\sum_{\ell=1}^{m} b_{\ell}^{2}\biggr)^{1/2}.
$$

Fix a positive radius $r$, and let $W_{m,r}$ be the "wall" consisting of all points $(x_{k})_{k=1}^{n} = (x_{1}, \cdots x_{n})$ in Cartesian $n$-space such that
$$
r^{2} < x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + \cdots + x_{m}^{2} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} x_{k}^{2}.
$$
Geometrically, the wall is the result of "boring an $m$-dimensional hole of radius $r$ out of $n$-space. Alternatively, we can "slice" the wall by setting $x_{m+1} = \cdots = x_{n} = 0$, namely, by intersecting with the copy of $m$-space embedded in $n$-space as the set of points where the first $m$ coordinates vary freely and the others are $0$.

---

The question is, "Under what conditions can we move the cuboid, in an arbitrary axis orientation, by translations through the sliced wall?" Equivalently, "Under what conditions can we place a translated copy of $C$ (after an arbitrary axis-permuting rotation) inside the complement of $W_{m,r}$, i.e., inside the Cartesian product of the $m$-ball and $(n - m)$-dimensional space?"

The necessary and sufficient condition is, every $m$-dimensional slice of $C$ has diameter at most $2r$. In a specific example, it suffices to pick "the $m$ largest lengths."

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, It helped me a lot!